# Don't understand why this quadratic form can vanish only two times on the arc [-π/2, π/2]

Tags: linear-algebra, roots, quadratic-forms, parametrization

I am currently dissecting a paper by Lloyd L. Dines, but i got stuck on the proof of the first proposition because the autor used some fact which I'm not sure I understood, he must have considered it too trivial to explicitly write what he was using. His paper is [On the mapping of quadratic forms](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183503694).

I will expose only the part of his reasoning essential to my doubt, without missing any ideas hopefuly. Given a quadratic form $S:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies
$$S(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)=k^2>0, \qquad \text{for} \qquad \theta=-\pi/2, 0, \pi/2$$
Then $S(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$ can vanish for at most two values of theta between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$, and must be negative for theta between those values, then $S(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$ must be strictly positive for $\theta \in [-\pi/2,0]$ or $\theta \in [0,\pi/2]$.
Wht I didn't understand is why $S$ can only be equal to zero twice for those values. Can anyone show me how to get to this conclusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most general quadratic form can be written as $$S(x,y)=ax^2+bxy+cy^2$$ However according to the assumptions it must satisfy $$S(1,0)=S(0,1)=S(0,-1)=k^2$$ and thus this yields $a=c=k^2$. We can therefore write $$S(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)=k^2(1+\frac{b}{k^2}\sin 2\theta)$$ and from this all claims of the paper follow.

More specifically, $S(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)=0$ is only possible if $\sin2\theta=-\frac{k^2}{b}$, but since $k\neq 0$ this equation has at most two solutions in 
$(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. Also if one of the solutions is $\theta=x$, then the other one is given by $\theta=\text{sgn}(-b)\text{sgn}(x)\frac{\pi}{2}-x$.

Furthermore, we note that since $\sin2\theta<0~~ \forall~x\in(-\pi/2,0)$ and positive otherwise we conclude that if  $b<0(>0)$ then $S(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)>1>0$ if $x\in(-\pi/2,0)\Big(x\in(0, \pi/2)\Big)$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it realy was simpler than I was expecting. I have one comment to add though. A simpler formula for the second root is $$\theta = sgn(x)\pi/2 - x$$. And to see why it is true note that since $\sin2\theta=sin2x$, then $2\theta$ and $2x$ must be symetric in relation to $sgn(x)\pi/2$, then you can note that $2\theta+2x=sgn(x)\pi$, for example, in the case where x is positive, then $2x=\pi/2+d$ and $2\theta=\pi/2-d$ (symmetry) where $d$ is the distance from $\pi/2$ positive or negative, then $2x+2\theta=\pi/2+d+\pi/2-d=\pi$.